# SmtpClient becomes progressively slower

Tags: smtpclient

I am using SmtpClient (.NET 3.5, VS 2008) for mass mailings.  The code below starts with about 2 seconds per send and deteriorates to more than 20 seconds per send after the foreach loop has processed about 30 addresses and proceeds to deteriorate.  Any ideas?

Jim

```
// Setup Client
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, 587);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smptLogin, smtpPassword);

// Send mail
foreach (string address in addresses)
{
    MailMessage message = BuildMessage(body);
    message.To.Clear();
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));

    client.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: What SMTP server are you sending to?

Answer (score 4):

The provider running the host you're connecting to might be implementing throttling as an anti-spam measure.

It looks like the content of your mail doesn't change per-recipient.  In an enterprise environment, I would send a single mail, not dozens, and add recipients to the Bcc list.  You might try this.